# GAE datastore + JPA + Odata in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, odata, datanucleus

I am creating an application on **GAE** in which I have to provide a rest interface of database(datastore) using **odata**. I am using odata4j library for odata producer implementation. I am new to odata. I have provided a access layer on GAE datastore using **jpa**. Now what's my problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Submission")
//@IdClass(java.lang.Long.class)
public class Submission implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic
private Long submissionId;

private String status;
private Long userId;
private Date createdDate;

public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public Long getSubmissionId() {
    return submissionId;
}

public void setSubmissionId(Long submissionId) {
    this.submissionId = submissionId;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}
```

I have simple Entity `Submission`. Through `EntityManager` I persistent some `Submission` entities. When I hit the following odata url i get the all submissions

```
http://localhost:8888/odata.svc/Submission
```

I have some other entities and this work for all entities. I use `$filter` to query on entities and it works too. Now when I want to get a single entity using its `id(primary key)` I am getting the error that **invalid key type**. OData URL for getting single `submission` is

```
http://localhost:8888/odata.svc/Submission(12345567889)
```

After debuging the odata library what I found that in static method

```
typeSafeEntityKey(EntityManager em,EntityType<?> jpaEntityType,OEntityKey entityKey)
```

of `JPAProducer` class in odata library, there is a line from which we try to find out the type of id of submission entity

```
 Class<?> javaType = jpaEntityType.getIdType().getJavaType();
```

after getting the type we then try to find out what is its type. I am expecting that the `id` type should be `java.lang.Long` but It always give `javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity`. In odata4j this type is not a valid due to which it throw exception.

Upon more debugging I found that the `Submission` entity has the @id-class value `javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity` due to which `getIdType()` function give the id type `LongIdentity`.

In my submission entity class I try to use @Idclass annotation with value `java.lang.Long` but I get the error in console that

```
 **Class "com.convergent.model.Submission" has been specified with an object-id class   java.lang.Long which doesnt have a default constructor. All objectId classes MUST have a   default constructor.**
```

I don't know what to do because I am unable to use `@Idclass` and `getIdType()` give the `LongIdentity` type of id. thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this issue have been known since March 2012 and still not resolved: https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/detail?id=149

Most probable odata4j doesn't support DataNucleus as a JPA `ODataProducer`. Nevertheless it is [stated](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) that it supports AppEngine's Datastore directly, here is example: http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/browse?repo=samples&name=0.4#hg%2Fodata4j-appengine

It should be possible to use odata4j with AppEngine's Datastore directly and simultaneously use JPA in other parts of your application, but one should be careful with caching.

### UPDATE:

It looks like odata4j is dead, there have been no new releases since August 2012 and signs of development activity since April 2013... So I suggest you to find an alternative. You may try [Apache Olingo](http://olingo.apache.org/), it should support GAE now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-150

Comment: then what type i use for the primary key in Submission Entity? Long or SubmissionId.

Comment: I test your suggestion but It don't solve the issue. In odata4j class TypeConverter find out the value of id-class of entity submission which is submissionId. Odata4j don't know that type and that's why it throws exception. If we use a custom id-class then the problem is same.

Comment: Oh sorry, my answer was wrong, but I have rewritten it.

Comment: I have already try to use odata4j directly on google datastore, but It rises some other issues.

Comment: I think your answer is well suited for my this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883770/odata-service-on-gae-datastore?lq=1